# Error when reading HDF files in Python 3.7 with Pandas.read_hdf function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

Previously, I have saved multi columns of dataset into one HDF file. The procedure can be outlined as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import HDFStore, DataFrame
from pandas import read_hdf

hdf = HDFStore("FILE.h5")
feature =  ['var1','var2']
## noted that the original dataframe is huge, and thus fake dataframe was generated as example.
for k in range(0,len(feature),1):
    df = {'A':['1','2','3','4'],'B':[4,5,6,7]}
    df  = pd.DataFrame(df)
    hdf.put(feature[k], df, format='table', encoding="utf-8")
```

Then, I can read the file 'FILE.h5' by simply using

```
df = pd.read_hdf("./FILE.h5,'var1',encoding = 'utf-8')
```

It always worked well until I have upgraded my Python environment from 2.7 to 3.7.

For now with Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.24.2, the HDF file could not be correctly read. The error shows like:

```
df = pd.read_hdf("./FILE.h5,'var1',encoding = 'utf-8')
>>> ...
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py in getdecoder(encoding)
    961 
    962     """
--> 963     return lookup(encoding).decode
    964 
    965 def getincrementalencoder(encoding):

TypeError: lookup() argument must be str, not numpy.bytes_
```

### PS

I have read the github [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17540) which was similar to my situation. But it could not fix my problem. Then, I turned to use **h5py** package dealing with hdf5-format files, but it was not as convenient as the pandas.

Any advices or methods was highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a prior bug with pandas (since you're using version 0.13). From Github Issues [12304](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12304) and [11126](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11126) indicate that there's a bug in `read_hdf` when you attempt to pass encodings in versions under 0.17.

Is upgrading to a modern version of pandas an option since you are already on 3.7?

Comment: Thanks, I'll re-check the Pandas version, and reply to you later.

Comment: Sorry to noted that my pandas version is 0.24.2. I have corrected my question